# Cannot import aws boto3 on python 2.7.6

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-import, boto3

I am using Python 2.7.6 and created a virtual environment.
Inside the `virtualenv`, I installed `boto3` using `pip install boto3`.
Its installed, and I can verify this by going into the `site-packages` folder and see the boto3 folder. But, I am not able to import it in my python file, which is showing `ImportError: No module named boto3` on execution.

To test it out, I installed requests, using `pip install requests` and tried to import requests, and its working just fine. The issue is only with importing boto3.

I have explicitly chosen the python 2.7.6 interpreter which is inside the virtualenv.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

**UPDATE**

`boto3` is installed inside the `virtualenv`, but if I install it outsize virtualenv i.e. globally, it works(import), and thus the new question arises, why Python is not able to import boto3 if installed inside a virtualenv?

Comment: check if the site-packages is a subdirectory of python2.4 or default python2.7

Comment: its inside python2.7, I just checked

Comment: Try activate the environment using source and do the installation. 
e.g. 

source /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/your_env_name/bin/activate